# Is there a better way to roll up child data into a list outside of the database?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following dataset, where columns 1-3 are from a parent table and columns 4-6 are from a joined child table (single parent to zero or more children).

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
a    |  b   | c    |  1   |   2  |  3
a    |  b   | c    |  4   |   5  |  6
d    |  e   | f    |  7   |   8  |  9
g    |  h   | i    | null | null | null
```

As you can see, the data from the parent table is repeated when there are multiple children. I cannot change the fact that I'm receiving this denormalized data, but I can ship it back out in whatever format I like. I'd like to roll it up in a single item per parent, using the following two POCOs (forgive the contrived names):

```
public class ParentPoco {
    public object Col1 { get; set; }
    public object Col2 { get; set; }
    public object Col3 { get; set; }
    public List<ChildPoco> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildPoco {
    public object Col4 { get; set; }
    public object Col5 { get; set; }
    public object Col6 { get; set; }
}
```

My expected output for the sample data above would be a list of 3 `ParentPoco`s. The first would have a list of two `ChildPoco`s, the second would have a list of one `ChildPoco`, and the third would have an empty list of `ChildPoco`s.

**My question is**: what is the most <strike>efficient</strike> expressive, concise way to roll up this data? I was able to get what I wanted by grouping by all of the parent table columns (see below), but this method seems inelegant. It *feels* like there is a better way to do this -- perhaps a way that is more generic, only requiring you to specify the parent columns once -- but I just can't figure out what that way is.

One way to get what I want (works but feels heavy handed):

```
var rolledUp = from parent in myData
               group parent by new { parent.Col1, parent.Col2, parent.Col3 } into grouped
               select new ParentPoco
               {
                   Col1 = grouped.Key.Col1,
                   Col2 = grouped.Key.Col2,
                   Col3 = grouped.Key.Col3,
                   Children = grouped.Where(child => child.Col4.HasValue)
                                     .Select(child => new ChildPoco
                                     {
                                         Col4 = grouped.Key.Col4,
                                         Col5 = grouped.Key.Col5,
                                         Col6 = grouped.Key.Col6,
                                     }).ToList()
               }
```

Comment: To clarify, I do not care (much) about performance, I'm looking for clarity of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: what is the most efficient way to roll up this data?

If you absolutely need the best possible performance, you're probably better off not using Linq and fine tuning to exactly what you need. That said, Linq adds an amazing amount of expressiveness to your code that is often worth the negligible performance hit. Does it perform well now? If so, leave it and enjoy the fact that other people can easily make sense of it. If you're wondering if there's a better way to do this using Linq, then I think your current code is about as good as it's going to get.

> this method seems inelegant

Looks fine to me. It looks very clear to me what this code is trying to accomplish, so what more could you ask for? How likely are you to need this exact type of transformation elsewhere? A generic version of your code would need to know just about as many things as your code already expresses:

```
myData.GroupByParent(p => new ParentPoco { Col1 = p.Col1, Col2... },
    p.Children,
    c => new ChildPoco { Col4 = c.Col4, Col5... },
    c => c.Col4.HasValue);
```

Looks ugly to me. *Maybe* you could define an object to hold the common properties and use it as a constructor argument:

```
myData.GroupBy (x => new ParentPocoArgs { Col1 = x.Col1... })
      .Select (g => new ParentPoco(g.Key)
      {
          Children = g.Where(...
      })
```

Doesn't really buy you much...I suspect these reasons are why there are no other answers to this question.

Comment: I don't know why I used the word "efficient", that was a dumb word to use because performance actually isn't my concern. I care about expressiveness and conciseness (perhaps my brain was trying to convey "efficient use of symbols"). In any case, you've addressed the core of my question quite thoroughly, thank you.